# "^[[O" appearing on Vim when focus lost

Tags: vim

I am having this strange issue on my terminal when I am working on Vim.

For example if am working on a file and switch to postman, when I come back I find this characters where the cursor was: `^[[O`

Lately it has been happening more often and I wonder if any has had the same experience and how you solve it.

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Perhaps this will help: [“^[[O” and “^[[I” appearing on iTerm2 when focus lost](https://superuser.com/q/931873)

Comment: Thank you @Jorengarenar. Thank you also for the editing. Looks clearer this way.
I am experiencing this problem only on vim and I am using the regular terminal app on my mac.
This is new. I have been using Vim for quite a while so I am now looking into what plugin did I introduce recently that made things change. No luck so far.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [link from comments](https://superuser.com/a/1017817): Try hitting <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> while terminal is open, to reset focus reporting

Answer (score 0):

I was using neovim on **windows terminal preview** with **powershell**, as soon as i close my neovim, `^[[O` character used to print on the terminal. Then i switched to **windows terminal** (without preview) and this fixed my problem. So i think that issue was with the **windows terminal preview**.